# Rails 4. Gem creating. Include rubyzip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubyzip

I'm creating my own gem(mountable plugin), and I need to include an older version of rubyzip gem. The reason for using the old version is that I have some code templates written in Rails 3. In the gemfile I include the old version as follows:

```
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 0.9.9"
```

It installs successfully. In the lib file where I wrote my gem-module I've added:

```
require 'devise' # work nice.. haven't any error.
require 'zip/zip' # give me error that it is not found
```

If I try `require zip` doesn't work either. If I don't require the gem in my lib file, the error disappeared but in the gem's controller I don't have access to `Zip` constant anymore.

Comment: If you run `gem list` in command line, what version of rubyzip do you see installed ?

Comment: 'rubyzip (1.1.6, 0.9.9)'. But if you ask about 'bundle install' - "Using rubyzip 0.9.9"